# How cashback websites track transaction summary on retailers shops?

Tags: cookies, e-commerce, analytics

I'm planning to build a cashback site, but I'm confused on how the system work.

After googling i found [this answer on Quora](http://www.quora.com/How-do-the-coupon-cashback-and-rebate-online-sites-work/answer/Panda-Cash-Back):

> There is a tracking mechanism into the process. When you sign up to cash back site like fatwallet, the site create for you an ID, this ID is passed through your cookies, when you click on the link of the cash back site to the retailer. When a sale take place, the tracking mechanism send the transaction summary to the rebate website with your id so the store can link it back to you.

Is it possible to track such information? If possible, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Waiting for this question to be answered.